# Normalizing audio, how to convert a float array to a byte array?

Tags: c#, audio, floating-point, arrays, normalization

Hi all, I am playing an audio file. I read it as a `byte[]` and then I need to normalize the audio by putting values into range of [-1,1]. I want to then put each float value into a `byte[i]` array and then put that `byte[]` back into the playing audio player.

I've tried this:

```
byte[] data = ar.ReadData();
byte[] temp=new byte[data.Length];
float biggest= 0; ;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    if (data[i] > biggest)
    {
        biggest= data[i];
    }
}
```

This part of code should put for example 0.43 int byte[] if that is even possible I tried this but it's not working:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    temp = BitConverter.GetBytes(data[i] * (1 / biggest));
}
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a good description of the problem - and your sample code is looping without taking any account of the changes to temp... It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, either. Sometimes you're using each byte as a separate value, and sometimes not...

Comment: I mean it is working but it is giving me all the 0 into an temp array

Comment: That's why I asked..I need to have at the end array of bytes beetween [-1,1] if that is possible

Comment: Bytes are unsigned, and only integer values. You're really not explaining clearly what you want.

Comment: You're *still* not being clear about what you want in the byte array. Do you understand that if you're trying to store `float` values, each `float` will take 4 bytes? And that in the code you've given for reading from `data`, `biggest` will always be positive, and at most 255? It feels like you're fundamentally missing how bytes and floats work...

Comment: What does the return value of `ReadData` mean? If it's audio samples you almost certainly *shouldn't* be taking the biggest byte from the array... you should be considering several bytes at a time...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a comment, you stated "*I am playing audio file... I read it as byte[] and then I need to normalize audio by putting values into range of [-1,1] and then I need to put that byte[] back into playing audio player*"

I am making a big assumption here, but I'm guessing the the data you receive from `ar.ReadData()` is a byte array of 2-channel 16-bit/44.1kHz PCM data. (side note: are you using the Alvas.Audio library?) If that is the case, here is how to do what you want.

### Background

First, a little background. A 2-channel, 16-bit PCM data stream looks like this:

```
   byte | 01 02 | 03 04 | 05 06 | 07 08 | 09 10 | 11 12 | ...
channel |  Left | Right | Left  | Right | Left |  Right | ...
  frame |     First     |    Second     |     Third     | ...
 sample | 1st L | 1st R | 2nd L | 2nd R | 3rd L | 3rd R | ... etc.
```

It's important here to take note of a few things:

1. Since the audio data is 16-bit, a single sample from a single channel is a `short` (2 bytes), not an `int` (4 bytes), with a value in the range -32768 to 32767.
2. This data is in [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) representation, and unless your architecture is also little-endian, you can't use the .NET [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class for the conversion.
3. We don't have to split the data into per-channel streams, because we are normalizing both channels based on the single highest value from either channel.
4. Converting a floating-point value to an integer value will result in quantization errors, so you probably want to use some sort of [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) (which is an entire topic in its own right).

### Helper Functions

Before we jump into the actual normalization, let's make this easier on ourselves by writing a couple of helper functions to get a `short` from a `byte[]` and vice-versa:

```
short GetShortFromLittleEndianBytes(byte[] data, int startIndex)
{
    return (short)((data[startIndex + 1] << 8)
         | data[startIndex]);
}

byte[] GetLittleEndianBytesFromShort(short data)
{
    byte[] b = new byte[2];
    b[0] = (byte)data;
    b[1] = (byte)(data >> 8 & 0xFF);
    return b;
}
```

### Normalization

An important distinction should be made here: [audio normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_normalization) is **not** the same as [statistical normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)). Here we are going to perform peak normalization on our audio data, amplifying the signal by a constant amount so that its peak is at the upper limit. To peak normalize audio data, we first find the largest value, subtract it from the upper limit (for 16-bit PCM data, this is 32767) to get an offset, and then increase each value by this offset.

So, to normalize our audio data, first scan through it to find the peak magnitude:

```
byte[] input = ar.ReadData();  // the function you used above
float biggest = -32768F;
float sample;
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
{
    sample = (float)GetShortFromLittleEndianBytes(input, i);
    if (sample > biggest) biggest = sample;
}
```

At this point, `biggest` contains the largest value from our audio data. Now to perform the actual normalization, we subtract `biggest` from 32767 to get a value which corresponds to the offset from peak of the loudest sample in our audio data. Next we add this offset to each audio sample, effectively increasing the volume of each sample until our loudest sample is at the peak value.

```
float offset = 32767 - biggest;

float[] data = new float[input.length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2)
{
    data[i / 2] = (float)GetShortFromLittleEndianBytes(input, i) + offset;
}
```

The last step is to convert the samples from floating-point to integer values, and store them as little-endian `short`s.

```
byte[] output = new byte[input.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i += 2)
{
    byte[] tmp = GetLittleEndianBytesFromShort(Convert.ToInt16(data[i / 2]));
    output[i] = tmp[0];
    output[i + 1] = tmp[1];
}
```

And we're done! Now you can send the `output` byte array, which contains the normalized PCM data, to your audio player.

As a final note, keep in mind that this code isn't the most efficient; you could combine several of these loops, and you could probably use `Buffer.BlockCopy()` for the array copying, as well as modifying your `short` to `byte[]` helper function to take a byte array as a parameter and copy the value directly into the array.
I didn't do any of this so as to make it easier to see what's going on.

And as I mentioned before, you should *absolutely* read up on dithering, as it will vastly improve the quality of your audio output.

I've been working on an audio project myself, so I figured all this out through some trial-and-error; I hope it helps somebody somewhere.

Comment: Your definition for a sample is actually describing a frame. A sample is actually a single value representing the amplitude of a sound wave for *one* channel. A frame is like a multichannel version of a sample, it's a snapshot of *all* channels.

Comment: @alldayremix: very nice answer. I have a question. What is the opposite of this normalizing process? How can I denormalize it? For example, if I normalize an array of audio samples, take it's FFT, apply some gain, then IFFT, how do I denormalize the result?

Comment: Save the value for `biggest` you got when normalizing, and then after your processing, normalize the data again, but instead of using 32767 for your peak value, use `biggest`

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do this using Uint8List in dart.
Basically I have input file with type `Uint8List` and I would like to normalize it.
I tried to convert your code into dart but i am still not finding the result

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
float number = 0.43f;
byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
```

What does not work for you?

Comment: I do not really understand what the problem is and what you try to achieve. Put a break point in the beginning of your code and use F10 to step through it. You should be able to see where it goes wrong for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Math.Abs(sample) > biggest) biggest = sample;
```

I would change this to:

```
if (Math.Abs(sample) > biggest) biggest = Math.Abs(sample);
```

Because if the biggest value is negative you will multiply all values with a negative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) like this:

```
float[] floats = new float[] { 0.43f, 0.45f, 0.47f };
byte[] result = new byte[sizeof(float) * floats.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(floats, 0, result, 0, result.Length);
```

Comment: can I use this if your floats are byte array, like I have it in my code?

Comment: No. You question doesn't state anything about floats being byte array. You are asking how to convert floats to byte arrays.

Comment: Yes at the end I get value as float and I want to put it into byte[]

Answer (score 0):

You can change `temp` to a list of byte arrays to avoid overwriting it all the time.

```
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };  // sample data
    IList<byte[]> temp = new List<byte[]>(data.Length);
    float biggest = 0; ;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] > biggest)
            biggest = data[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        temp.Add(BitConverter.GetBytes(data[i] * (1 / biggest)));
    }
```